# Why does my array print numbers that are different to the numbers printed during assigning process?

Tags: c, arrays, output

I'm using the ASCII value of characters to do this: `abs(string[j-1] - string[j])` and store it in the integer array 'arraynum2'. ('string' holds 4 characters)

```
for(int j = length; j > 0; j--) {
        int num = 0;
        number2 = abs(string[j-1] - string[j]);
        printf("second %d\n", number2);
        arraynum2[num] = number2;
        printf("second %d\n", arraynum2[num]);
        num++;
    }
```

The above for loop prints the right numbers, as in `number2 == arraynum2[num]`.

But when I print out the next for loop, different numbers get printed:

```
    for(int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        printf("arraynum2 has: %d\n", arraynum2[k]);
        /*
        if(arraynum1[k] != arraynum2[k]) {
            return 0;
        }
        */
    }
```

For example, the array should contain: 122, 2, 21, 2.
But in the second for loop, it prints out: 2, 0, 673946096, 32730.

Could someone explain what I did wrong or what I'm not seeing?

Comment: please post a small, compiles cleanlly, shows the problem code.  Then we can correctly help you.   As it is, there are several key un-disclosed details, such as: 1) value of length  2) definition of string[].   If the sizeof(string) is equal to length, then the code access memory beyond the end of string[].  I.E. runtime questions need runnable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your first loop you re-initialize `num` to `0` at *every iteration*. So you'll only assign to the first element, `arraynum2[0]` every time.

Initialize `num` *outside* your first loop:

```
for (int j = length; j > 0; j--) {
    int num = 0;
```

Or:

```
for (int j = length, num = 0; j > 0; j--) {
    int num = 0;
```

Also, as others have pointed out, the index `length` is likely outside the bounds of your string (you don't show the definition of `string`). So you may need to start your loop(s) at index `length - 1`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that fixed it :D

Comment: Or throw out `num` entirely and just use `[length-j]` as the array subscript, though I still concur with tinky as well; chances are the boundaries are being overreached regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are triggering undefined behavior by trying to read out of range

```
for(int j = length; j > 0; j--) {
        int num = 0;
        number2 = abs(string[j-1] - string[j]);
```

If your `string[]` array is of size length, defined like

```
int string[length];
```

then the last index is `length - 1`.

Additionally in the first loop you assign incorrectly to `arraynum2`, because you use always only `0` index:

```
int num = 0;
number2 = abs(string[j-1] - string[j]);
printf("second %d\n", number2);
arraynum2[num] = number2;
           ^
        // num is always 0 here
```

---

SOLUTION:

Check that you do not trigger **UB** and initialize `num` once, in the initialization step of *for* loop:

```
for(int j = length, num = 0; j > 0; j--) {
        number2 = (...);
        arraynum2[num] = number2;
        num++;
}
```